# How to use pandas ffill every 15 minutes

Tags: python, pandas

I am curious as to how I can change this:

```
df_pirates_all = pd.read_csv(
    "https://cdn.touringplans.com/datasets/pirates_of_caribbean_dlr.csv",usecols=['date','datetime','SPOSTMIN'],
    parse_dates=['date', 'datetime'], 
)
df_pirates_all['ride'] = 'pirates'
df_pirates_all['open'] = ~((df_pirates_all['SPOSTMIN'] == -999))

df_pirates = df_pirates_all.set_index('datetime').sort_index()
df_pirates = df_pirates.loc['2017-01-01 06:00':'2017-02-01 00:00']
df_pirates = df_pirates.where(df_pirates.fillna(axis=1, method='ffill').isnull(), df_pirates.fillna(0))
df_pirates = df_pirates.resample('15Min').ffill()
```

so that it does not put data every 15 minutes once the park is closed for the night as the current results shows the last wait time available for the day through the overnight hours as this code is my latest attempt at it.

Comment: I think the line `df_pirates = df_pirates.loc['2017-01-01 06:00':'2017-02-01 00:00']` filters the data to midnight. If you want to reduce that back to park close, change the second term to the park close time

Comment: I have it as that so I can have all of the January 2017 data in one excel sheet without having to change the time every single day of the entire dataset.

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry I was thinking the 2 was for the second day, not the second month. I'd add a new column basically splitting out the time, and then filter similarly on that column to get the right times. Though each  day the park may close at a different time... Not sure the best way to handle that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by looking at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.fillna.html and changed the last line from

```
df_pirates = df_pirates.resample('15Min').ffill()
```

to

```
df_pirates = df_pirates.resample('15Min').fillna("nearest",limit=1)
```

and it eliminated all the false overnight wait times.